# Django/React CSRF Failed: Origin checking failed - http://localhost:8000/ does not match any trusted origins

Tags: python, reactjs, django, rest

I am building a web application using Django for the backend, RestApi for information transfer, and ReactJs for the frontend. When I run a POST request, in which I send data from a form, I get an error: "CSRF Failed: Origin checking failed - http://localhost:8000/ does not match any trusted origins."This means that Django recognizes the question but rejects it for some unknown reason.

ReactJs is using a proxy to work with server data.  I've read already solved articles on forum such as [article 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70285834/forbidden-403-csrf-verification-failed-request-aborted-reason-given-for-fail), [article 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38841109/csrf-validation-does-not-work-on-django-using-https?noredirect=1&lq=1), [article 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64737794/django-rest-create-and-action-method-returns-error-403-forbidden), [article 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739987/http-403-in-django-rest-framework), their solutions didn't help me.

My request from ReactJs:

```
const item = {tittle : data.target.tittle.value, description : data.target.description.value};
axios({
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
     method : "post",
     url : "api/articles/",
     data : item
}).catch((e) => {console.log(e)})
```

Setting.py:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
'http://localhost:8000'
]
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
'localhost',
]
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
'http://localhost:8000',
]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

class for processing requests in views.py:

```
class ArticleList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        snippets = Articles.objects.all()
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helped me to add the authentication_classes = [] variable to the body of the class. Now my ArticleList class looks like this:

```
class ArticleList(generics.GenericAPIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        snippets = Articles.objects.all()
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```